# DataContext.ExecuteQuery parameter issues

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, system.data

I get the following error:

> Procedure or function 'procTestReport' expects parameter '@StartDate',
>   which was not supplied.

When I execute the following code:

```
String[] args = new String[2]{StartDate.ToShortDateString(), EndDate.ToShortDateString()};

lst = dbContext.ExecuteQuery<Summary>("procTestReport", args).ToList<Summary>();
```

Are the arguments I pass supposed to be presented in a different way? From the following link it seems like I'm using it correctly:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

Comment: you have to give the parameter name

Comment: @viveknuna great, can you show me an example how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to execute a stored procedure you can use instead:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your ConnectionString");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your SP_Name", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param name", "param value"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param2 name", "param2 value"));
.
.
.
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
con.Close();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);

return dt;
```

`dt` contains the return of the stored procedure.

If is necessary to use LinQ, try this

```
dataContext.ExecuteCommand("EXEC usp_SomeProcedure {0}, {1}, {2}", param1, param2, param3);
```

Comment: understood, but as per our shop, I have use datacontext to follow suit with previous code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare the parameters in your sql statement.  For example:

```
lst = dbContext.ExecuteQuery<Summary>("EXEC dbo.procTestReport @StartDate={0}, @EndDate={1}", args).ToList<Summary>();
```